# How to do Google Analytics for ajax call in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, google-analytics, tracking, urchin

I have a FBML game and need to track all ajax calls.

At the bottom of the page, I have this:

and in the javascript functions, I put this:

Facebook.urchinTracker("/ajaxcallname/");

However, it doesn't work.. and what I found out is that the utmac (the google account id) is empty!!! _uacct is empty!

even I set it in the FBML, it is still empty!! and  I can't find a way to dynamically set _uacct be my google account ID..  any one has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Your Tracking of ajax call  reflected in Google Analytics a/c after 72 Hrs.

Not Immediately.

& also check Your Urchin/Google Analytics account ID.

Comment: already checked.  but nothing. 
I'm wondering if FB blocks the urchinTracker.

Answer (score 0):

@seatoskyhk try to use this javascript in your html.
May be this one is helpful for you

> < script type="text/javascript">
>    var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : http://www.");
>   document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost +  "google-analytics.com/ga.js'
>   type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
>  < /script> 
>    < script> type="text/javascript">
>    try { 
> var  pageTracker =  _gat._getTracker("UA-xxxxxxxx-x"); 
>    pageTracker._trackPageview();
>  }
>   catch(err) {}

Comment: Thanks.  :)

at last, I just use the pixel to track it.  :)